# work with BIOS interrupts that execute by bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, disk, bios, interrupt

I want to work with directory and subfolder
and I want to do it by bootloader
but most of existing interrupts are available in dos mode
How can I find BIOS interrupts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to be using INT 13h and parsing the directory structure yourself.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13

Comment: tnx ,i have another question does it work on system emulators

Comment: That would depend on if the emulator chooses to emulate the BIOS.  I'd suspect that most would as otherwise it's hard to run pre-written code (since much of it will use the BIOS at least initially).

Comment: tnx,system emulator like qemu on linux i mean maybe it doesn't work as well as media

Comment: I've never used QEMU, so I don't know if it's processor only emulation or complete system.  It would work for sure on a full-blown virtual host, like VirtualBox.

Comment: As far as I know, QEMU runs a BIOS image that should install those basic interrupt services, Bochs would also be good.